# Html 5 Player pause issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create an HTML 5 Player. Everything works fine in other browsers bud in Chrome. If I try to pause and play the video more than 2 times in Chrome video doesn't play any more. All other browsers but chrome work fine.

```
<video id="myVideo" style="width:100%"></video>
<div id="videoControlsBar">
   <button id="playpausebtn">&#10074;&#10074;</button>
    <span id="curtimetext"></span> / <span id="durtimetext"></span>
</div>

var vid, playbtn;

function initializePlayer() {
    vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext");
    durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext");

    playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
    vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", seekTimeUpdate, false);
}

window.onload = initializePlayer();

function playPause() {

if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    playbtn.innerHTML = "&#10074;&#10074;";
}
else {
    vid.pause();
    playbtn.innerHTML = "&#9658";;
}
}

function seekTimeUpdate() {
    var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration);
    var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60);
    var cursecs = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60);
    var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
    var dursecs = Math.floor(vid.duration - durmins * 60);

    if (cursecs < 10) { cursecs = "0" + cursecs; }
    if (dursecs < 10) { dursecs = "0" + dursecs; }
    if (curmins < 10) { curmins = "0" + curmins; }
    if (durmins < 10) { durmins = "0" + durmins; }

    curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins + ":" + cursecs;
    durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins + ":" + dursecs;
}

$scope.$on('playVideo', function (event, data) {
    vid.src = "/Content/Videos/SetVideos/" + data.videoLink;
    vid.play();
});
```

Comment: you seeing any specific error in chrome console? It will be helpful..

Comment: Thank you. No error, just stop playing

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>iTech</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="680" height="320" controls="controls" autoplay="false">
<source src="mp3,mp4 file url">
</video></body></html>
```

or

```
<embed src="mp3,mp4 file url" width="700" height="500" loop="false" autostart="false/>
```

Tested & Working fine in Chrome.

Comment: I'm sure we could all Google for a tutorial or example - you should explain what is actually wrong with the person's actual code that they posted.